# microbit Python: When using time module, how to keep sleep() units in milliseconds?

Tags: python, time, module, sleep, bbc-microbit

In microbit muPython:  sleep(ms), the units is milliseconds.

However, if import time module and use sleep() then muPython uses time module’s sleep(s) which is units of full seconds.  Coder must substitute time module’s sleep_ms(ms) to get units of milliseconds.

If using time module, how can I force use of the ‘normal’ sleep(ms)?

Or more generally, how can I specify using any command from the ‘normal’ muPython as opposed to the same-spelled command from an imported module?

```
# Task: Show SAD, sleep 1 sec, show HAPPY
# Problem: HAPPY takes 17 minutes to appear
from microbit import *
from time import *
display.show(Image.SAD)
sleep(1000) # uses time.sleep(units=sec) so 1,000 sec
display.show(Image.HAPPY)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `from ... import ... as` notation.

```py
from microbit import sleep as microbit_sleep
from time import sleep as normal_sleep

microbit_sleep(1000) # sleeps for one second
normal_sleep(1000) # sleeps for much longer
```

Or, if you need everything in those two modules, just do a normal `import`.

```py
import microbit
import time

microbit.sleep(1000)
time.sleep(1)
```

`from ... import *` is generally considered bad Python style precisely for the reasons you've discovered here.  It's okay for really quick scripts, but best avoided as projects get larger and depend on more modules.

Comment: Thanks, Rob, for help.
I think I get the theory but left betixt and between.
If I do 
       from microbit import sleep as microbit_sleep
then I have to repeat for each microbit function, like display

if I do
    import microbit

Comment: Thanks, Rob, for help. I think I get the theory but on syntax I'm betwixt and between.

If I do 
       from microbit import sleep as microbit_sleep
then would have to repeat for each microbit function, including display?

I tried
    import microbit
But line with display.show() throws error "Name Not Recognized"

Am I being greedy to want to import all functions from a module wo/ individual lines to import & name each function? I was hoping that I could resolve ambiguity by just preface a command with its module name.

Again, thanks for your time.

Comment: The `from X import Y as Z` makes _only_ the function Y available, except it renames it Z.  If you don't need to rename it you can just `from X import Y`.

The normal way Python programmers import many functions at once is `from X import Y, Z, A, B, C`.

`import X` imports all (handwaving a little bit) functions from the module X, and makes them available as `X.Y()` ("call function Y located in module X").

Hope this helps.  If you need more help, just ask!

Comment: Thanks, Rob, for both theory and syntax